# Property 'campaign' was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, for-loop, if-statement, vuejs3, pinia

These are the issues i'm getting
[image]

Here below is the code that produces the problems, this part in particular:
[image]

When ever i;m trying to filter campaigns using company_id and product_id with v-if the problem occurs. Almost the same exact code works a few lines above filtering products. I have no idea what to do next. I tried refs and putting the mocked that into reactive variable and computeing it with a function but it didn;t work out.

```
<script setup>
    import CompanyItem from "./CompanyItem.vue";
    import ProductItem from "./ProductItem.vue";
    import CampaignItem from "./CampaignItem.vue";
    import { useCurrentCompanyStore } from "../stores/currentCompanyStore.js"
    import { useCurrentProductStore } from "../stores/currentProductStore.js"
    const companyStore = useCurrentCompanyStore();
    const productStore = useCurrentProductStore();
    const companies = 
    [
        {
            company_id: 1,
            name: 'Domain of Man',
            fund_balance: 100000,
            products_list: [
                {
                    product_id: 1,
                    name: 'gate'
                },
                {
                    product_id: 2,
                    name: 'exploration ship'
                },
                {
                    product_id: 3,
                    name: 'artifacts'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            company_id: 2,
            name: 'Hegemony',
            fund_balance: 200000,
            products_list: [
                {
                    product_id: 1,
                    name: 'toothbrash'
                },
                {
                    product_id: 2,
                    name: 'ore'
                },
                {
                    product_id: 3,
                    name: 'food'
                }
            ]
        },
    ];
    const campaigns = [
        {
            campaign_id: 1,
            company_id: 1,
            product_id: 1,
            campaign_name: "Gates for everyone",
            keywords: [
                "one for each",
                "limited offer"
            ],
            bid_amount: 25000,
            status: true,
            town: "Tarnow",
            radius: "10"
        },
        {
            campaign_id: 2,
            company_id: 1,
            product_id: 3,
            campaign_name: "Get them while they last",
            keywords: [
                "rare",
                "one for each",
                "limited offer"
            ],
            bid_amount: 25000,
            status: false,
            town: "Tarnow",
            radius: "10"
        },
        {
            campaign_id: 3,
            company_id: 3,
            product_id: 1,
            campaign_name: "Let the shine power your ship",
            keywords: [
                "electricity",
                "green technology",
            ],
            bid_amount: 25000,
            status: true,
            town: "Tarnow",
            radius: "10"
        }
    ];
</script>

<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="companies" >
            <CompanyItem v-for="company in companies" v-bind:key="company.company_id" :company-id="company.company_id">
                <template #name>
                    {{ company.name }}
                </template>
                <template #budget>
                    {{ company.fund_balance }}
                </template>
            </CompanyItem>
        </div>
        <div class="products">
            <template v-for="company in companies">
                <ProductItem 
                    v-for="product in company.products_list" 
                    v-bind:key="product.product_id" 
                    :id="company.company_id" 
                    v-if="companyStore.companyId === company.company_id"
                    :product-id="product.product_id">
                    <template #name>
                        {{ product.name }}
                    </template>
                </ProductItem>
            </template>
        </div>
        <div class="campaigns">
            <CampaignItem 
                v-for="campaign in campaigns"
                v-if="companyStore.companyId === campaign.company_id"
                v-bind:key="campaign.campaign_id"
                :id="campaign.campaign_id"
                >
                <template #name>
                    {{campaign.campaign_name}}
                </template>
            </CampaignItem>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "companies products campaigns";
}

.companies {
    grid-area: companies;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.products {
    grid-area: products;
}

.campaigns {
    grid-area: campaigns;
}
</style>
```

Here are stores:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useCurrentCompanyStore = defineStore({
  id: 'currentComapny',
  state: () => ({
    companyId: -1
  }),
  getters: {
    getCompanyId: (state) => state.companyId
  },
  actions: {
    change(newCompanyId) {
      this.companyId = newCompanyId;
    }
  }
})
```

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useCurrentProductStore = defineStore({
  id: 'currentProduct',
  state: () => ({
    productId: -1
  }),
  getters: {
    getCompanyId: (state) => state.productId
  },
  actions: {
    change(newProductId) {
      this.productId = newProductId;
    }
  }
})
```

Btw. if anybody wants to run it themself here is the git repo, its feature/frontend branch:
https://github.com/kuborek2/campaign_planer

Comment: Probably a typo: `compaign`, with an `o`. Look into your project.

Comment: I reverted it just to make a post, and already fixed the typo but gonna triple check it anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You must not use `v-if` and `v-for` on the same element because `v-if` will always be evaluated first due to implicit precedence.**

And exactly because of that, you are facing this error of undefined `company_id` as `v-for` is not executed yet and `v-if` is trying to access it.

Make the changes as suggested below and it should fix your error.

```js
<CampaignItem 
   v-for="campaign in campaigns"
   :key="campaign.campaign_id"
   :id="campaign.campaign_id"
>
   <template v-if="companyStore.companyId === campaign.company_id" #name>
       {{campaign.campaign_name}}
   </template>
</CampaignItem>
```

Click [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for) for the reference

Comment: Using ESlint could help regarding those kind of issues.